# Longest substrings of common length with the same parity

Tags: algorithms, strings, efficiency, substrings, algorithm-design

Given two sequences $a$ and $b$, find largest $x$ such that in $a$ there is substring $A$ and substring $B$ in $b$ meeting those conditions:

1. length of both $A$ and $B$ is equal to $x$;
2. sum of elements in $A$ has the same parity as sum of elements in $B$.

Lengths of $a$ and $b$ are up to $5\times10^5$, so simple $O(n^2)$ solution won't do.

Example:
$a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]$
$b = [3, 1, 3, 6]$
Answer: 3 (one of the possible solutions is $A = [2, 3, 4], B = [3, 1, 3]$).

I've thought about it for hours and can't find a solution. How to do this in linear or linearithmic time complexity?

I'm quite sure the problem can be simplified to for index $i$, storing only sum of elements up to $i$ modulo $2$. However, it doesn't help me much.

(The problem comes from a rather-old Israeli book תכנות תחרותי: סביב אתגרים ('Competetitive programming') by Mordechai Ben-Ari. The book isn't well known and I couldn't find any solution in Hebrew, so I translated the problem into English for a better chance of getting answer.)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @TopSekret! I just deleted my comment that contains a clue. I can only hope that I have not gone too far in my comment. This site is a fishing pond for various contest participants. It looks like I have to be even more vigilant. I can be certain that Yuval's answer below is not the algorithm intended by the Polish IT olympics and I suspect that **the acceptance of that answer is only a decoy of OP's true intention.** (Of course, I cannot have any further evidence hereof.)

Comment: You do realize @TopSekret 's question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99800/find-common-longest-subsequences-of-same-length-and-both-ends) is the same question as this after trivial transformation of the problem?

Comment: For each index $i$, store parity of sum between $0$ and $i$; then what you do have to do? Find common longest subsequences of same length and same both ends! (This is the "What if all numbers belong to a small closed range (like the max value is 3 or they are bits)?"--we then have exactly bits.)

Comment: We don't have any ball in your game. Not restoring any comments against their authors' will, but definitely deleting the conversation that has nothing to do with the question. Please use [chat] if you want to, well, chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an $O(n\log^2 n)$ solution.

The first step is to reduce to an easier problem:

> Given $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \{0,1\}$, determine, for all $0 \leq i \leq n$ and $b \in \{0,1\}$, whether there is a contiguous subarray of length $i$ whose sum is equal to $b$ modulo 2.

Applying this to both $A$ and $B$, we can solve the original problem in $O(n)$.

The basic idea is to use divide and conquer. Given an array $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, divide it into two arrays $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ and $x_{m+1},\ldots,x_n$ of roughly equal size. Every contiguous subarray of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ of length $i$ with parity $b$ has one of the following forms:

1. Contiguous subarray of $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ of length $i$ with parity $b$.
2. Contiguous subarray of $x_{m+1},\ldots,x_n$ of length $i$ with parity $b$.
3. The concatenation of a subarray $x_{m-i_1+1},\ldots,x_m$ of parity $b_1$ with a subarray $x_{m+1},\ldots,x_{m+i_2}$ of parity $b_2$, where $i_1+i_2 = i$ and $b_1+b_2 \equiv b \pmod{2}$.

We can determine whether subarrays of the first two forms exist, for all $i$ and $b$, by running the procedure recursively on the two halves. The interesting part is the third form. We start by determining the parity of all arrays of the form $x_{m-i_1+1},\ldots,x_m$ and of the form $x_{m+1},\ldots,x_{m+i_2}$ for all $i_1,i_2$, which takes time $O(n)$. Let $L_{b_1}$ be the set of $i_1$ such that $x_{m-i_1+1},\ldots,x_m$ has parity $b_1$, and define $R_{b_2}$ analogously. Using FFT (exercise), for each $b_1,b_2$ we can determine in $O(n\log n)$ the set $X_{b_1b_2}$ of $i$ such that there exist $i_1 \in L_{b_1}$ and $i_2 \in R_{b_2}$ summing to $i$. Given the sets $X_{b_1b_2}$ for all $b_1,b_2$, we can determine whether subarrays of the third form exist, for all $i$ and $b$.

In total, denoting the running time of our algorithm by $T(n)$, we get the recurrence
$$ T(n) = T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + O(n\log n), $$
whose solution is $T(n) = O(n\log^2 n)$.

Comment: It looks like there is an $O(n)$ algorithm, although $O(n\log^2n)$ with not huge constant multiplier might be enough for competitive programming.

Comment: Yes, that's not too surprising.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I understand everything but I can't imagine how to find the set $X_{b_1b_2}$ using FFT. If I understand correctly, it's as if we have two sets of numbers, let's call them $P$ and $Q$, and we want every possible sum of one number from $P$ and one from $Q$ (with the additional restriction that such sum will never exceed $n$). How to do that?

Comment: @Apass.Jack What is that algorithm? If you don't want to write everything, could you just give an overview? (If it's $O(n)$ then it doesn't require FFT and maybe I have a chance of understanding it )

Comment: Hint: FFT can be used to multiply polynomials.